# Failed to install virtualbox 6.1 to Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, virtualbox

I'm trying with no success to install VirtualBox on Ubuntu 20.04. It keeps failing with every try. I think I may have possibly created files that I no longer have permissions to remove. I'm using my personal PC and don't know how to elevate permissions.  I'm new to Ubuntu.

This is my script when I try to install VirtualBox:

```bsh
emsys@emsys:~/Downloads$ sudo su
[sudo] password for emsys: 
root@emsys:/home/emsys/Downloads# ls
virtualbox-6.1_6.1.16-140961~Ubuntu~eoan_amd64.deb
root@emsys:/home/emsys/Downloads# dpkg -i virtualbox-6.1_6.1.16-140961~Ubuntu~eoan_amd64.deb
Selecting previously unselected package virtualbox-6.1.
(Reading database ... 182383 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack virtualbox-6.1_6.1.16-140961~Ubuntu~eoan_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking virtualbox-6.1 (6.1.16-140961~Ubuntu~eoan) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of virtualbox-6.1:
 virtualbox-6.1 depends on libqt5core5a (>= 5.12.2); however:
  Package libqt5core5a is not installed.
 virtualbox-6.1 depends on libqt5gui5 (>= 5.4.0) | libqt5gui5-gles (>= 5.4.0); however:
  Package libqt5gui5 is not installed.
  Package libqt5gui5-gles is not installed.
 virtualbox-6.1 depends on libqt5opengl5 (>= 5.0.2); however:
  Package libqt5opengl5 is not installed.
 virtualbox-6.1 depends on libqt5printsupport5 (>= 5.0.2); however:
  Package libqt5printsupport5 is not installed.
 virtualbox-6.1 depends on libqt5widgets5 (>= 5.12.2); however:
  Package libqt5widgets5 is not installed.
 virtualbox-6.1 depends on libqt5x11extras5 (>= 5.6.0); however:
  Package libqt5x11extras5 is not installed.
 virtualbox-6.1 depends on libsdl1.2debian (>= 1.2.11); however:
  Package libsdl1.2debian is not installed.
 virtualbox-6.1 depends on python (<< 2.8); however:
  Package python is not installed.
 virtualbox-6.1 depends on python (>= 2.7); however:
  Package python is not installed.
 virtualbox-6.1 depends on python:any (>= 2.6.6-7~); however:

dpkg: error processing package virtualbox-6.1 (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for systemd (245.4-4ubuntu3.2) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.36.0-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.24-1ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.64ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.17-2) ...
Processing triggers for shared-mime-info (1.15-1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 virtualbox-6.1
root@emsys:/home/emsys/Downloads# apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED
  virtualbox-6.1
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 1 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 216 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 183132 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing virtualbox-6.1 (6.1.16-140961~Ubuntu~eoan) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.64ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.17-2) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.36.0-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for shared-mime-info (1.15-1) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.24-1ubuntu3) ...
root@emsys:/home/emsys/Downloads# sudo apt purge virtualbox
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package 'virtualbox' is not installed, so not removed
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.
root@emsys:/home/emsys/Downloads#
```

If I type `ls`, I get the following:

```
-virtualbox-6.1_6.1.16-140961~Ubuntu~eoan_amd64.deb
```

My folder computer `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` has 4 files they contain the following:

```
folder oracle.virtualbox.list=# deb http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian focal contrib

folder oracle.virtualbox.list.save=# deb http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian focal contrib

folder virtualbox.list=# deb [arch=amd64] http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian focal contrib

folder virtualbox.list.save=# deb [arch=amd64] http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian focal contrib
```

Do I need to delete these multiple files? Are they preventing the download? I cant amend these text files. I see the files say `debian focal` but when I type `ls` in the terminal its looking for `eoan`?!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've definitely done something incorrectly.

All you need to do to install VirtualBox is two simple commands:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install virtualbox
```

That's it!

That being said, if your actions have degraded your sources and if you've been attempting other installation methods and failing, these simple commands might not work anymore if the package in Ubuntu repositories conflicts with whatever else you've done.

---

At this point it's unclear what you've done to break your package management system, but it looks like you've spawned more than one problem in your attempts to stab at this.

Do you remember or did you document every single change?  If not, your best path may be a system reinstall at this point.